# DRF: values() does not return groupby object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Suppose I have:

```
# models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subproject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    physical_pct = models.FloatField()
    cost = models.FloatField()

# serializers.py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

In my viewset, I want to display a grouped by object by name that will later be annotated. I referred to this example from [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values).

```
# views.py
class ProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Project.objects.values('project')
        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

When I print `queryset` it displays a list of all project without the other fields in the terminal. However it raises an error:

```
"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `subproject` on serializer `ProjectSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'subproject'."
```

My desired output is a json grouped by the `project` field.

**UPDATE 1:**

It will not have an error if I put all fields in the `values()` arguments i.e.

```
.values('project', 'subproject', 'physical_pct', 'cost',)
```

Which now then destroy the purpose of values being grouped by.

Comment: The query you are making is `SELECT project from appname_project` therefore other fields are not fetched, in your class Meta set fields = ('project',), if you want other behavior show a expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Main cause of the problem is for your `serializer` defination. If you only want to return back `project` field response make sure you are using appropriate serializer for that.

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__' // this means you are suppose to pass all model fields
```

So we need custom serializer for this purpose

```
class ProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('project',)
```

And also we need to update get_serializer method according to our necessary need

```
# views.py
class ProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):


    def get_queryset(self):
        // If you are doing so you are suppose to have only one 'project' field response 
        queryset = Project.objects.values('project')

        return queryset

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list' or self.action == 'retrive':
           return ProjectListSerializer
        return  ProjectSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
queryset = Project.objects.all().values('project')
```

Comment: Stated above: ```"Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `subproject` on serializer `ProjectSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `dict` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'subproject'."```

Comment: In views make sure. from .models import Project, def get_query(self): queryset = Project.objects.all().values('project')

Comment: You can see that above. I have it.

Comment: class ProjectsViewSet(APIView): def get(self): queryset = Project.objects.all().values('project')

Comment: Had this error: ```"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."```

Comment: why APIView tho?

Answer (score 0):

You are querying only project field in Project model but trying to serialize all field in Project model. If you want to serialize one field, you don't need the serializer:

```
class ProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    queryset = Project.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.get_queryset().values_list('project', flat=True)
        return Response(qs)
```

Comment: I need to serialize all of them since I will annotate later.

Comment: I want this example: ```>>> Author.objects.values('name').annotate(average_rating=Avg('book__rating'))``` to work for me. Link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#values